# Winnovative HTML to PDF open PDF after generated and open printer dialog automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, printing, winnovative

I'm using Winnovative HTML to PDF with MVC 4. The basic example works fine (below is the code) but I need the user do a click in "Print button", the code must to  generate the PDF, also I need open the PDF generated and open printer dialog box automatically (the user wants to press the least amount of clicks to print a document):

In my View Index.cshtml I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ImpresionSeccionVistaActual", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{       
    <input type="submit" id="impresion" name="impresion" value="imprimir sólo sección" />
}
```

In my HomeController I have:

```
using Winnovative;

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ImpresionSeccionVistaActual(FormCollection collection)
        {
            object model = null;
            ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

            // transmit the posted data to view
            viewData.Add("nombre", collection["nombre"]);

            // The string writer where to render the HTML code of the view
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

            // Render the Index view in a HTML string
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "Seccion", null);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    ControllerContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewData,
                    new TempDataDictionary(),
                    stringWriter
                    );
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);

            // Get the view HTML string
            string htmlToConvert = stringWriter.ToString();

            // Get the base URL
            String currentPageUrl = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            String baseUrl = currentPageUrl.Substring(0, currentPageUrl.Length - "Home/Seccion".Length);

            // Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
            HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

            //htmlToPdfConverter.OpenAction.Action = New PdfActionJavaScript("print()")

            htmlToPdfConverter.JavaScriptEnabled = true;            

            // Set license key received after purchase to use the converter in licensed mode
            // Leave it not set to use the converter in demo mode
            htmlToPdfConverter.LicenseKey = key;

            // Set an adddional delay in seconds to wait for JavaScript or AJAX calls after page load completed
            // Set this property to 0 if you don't need to wait for such asynchcronous operations to finish
            htmlToPdfConverter.ConversionDelay = 2;

            // Convert the HTML string to a PDF document in a memory buffer
            byte[] outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(htmlToConvert, baseUrl);

            // Send the PDF file to browser
            FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(outPdfBuffer, "application/pdf");
            fileResult.FileDownloadName = "ImpresionSeccionVistaActual.pdf";            

            return fileResult;
        }
```

The View Seccion.cshtml only have:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Seccion ejemplo";
    var nombre = ViewBag.Nombre;    
}
```

What I have done today is that the click, display the PDF downloaded at the bottom of the browser, like the attached image.[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself. First, I change the View adding target _blank:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ImprimeVistaExterna", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { target= "_blank" }))
{
    <input type="submit" id="impresion2" name="impresion2" value="ver pdf generado directo en otra pestaña" />
}
```

Second, in the Controller I change a little and used a Document and I added the Print Javascript function:

```
... // same code
byte[] outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(url);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(outPdfBuffer);

Document document = new Document(stream);
document.LicenseKey = "myKey";
document.OpenAction.Action = new PdfActionJavaScript("print()");
byte[] b = document.Save();
Stream strm = new MemoryStream(b);

Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=file.pdf");
return new FileStreamResult(strm, "application/pdf");
```

The result to clic the print button is the image below and this show in a new tab in browser:
[image]

Regards!